# I'm getting an error no default constructor available for android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat;

Tags: android

I'm getting an error:

```
No default constructor available for android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat;
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.dell.treblemusic;

import android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat;

class SpinletViewPager$MockEdgeEffectCompat extends EdgeEffectCompat
{
   public boolean onAbsorb(int var1)
   {
      return false;
   }

   public boolean onPull(float var1) {
      return false;
   }

  public boolean onRelease() {
     return false;
  }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Stackoverflow is no debugger. Read your error message it says all you have to do.

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can make a constructor in your class like this

```
public SpinletViewPager$MockEdgeEffectCompat(Context context){
    super(context);
}
```